# Flask-Login vs Flask-Security for Production Environment

Tags: python, security, flask, production-environment

I am building out a feature for users to register, login, authenticate and authorize themselves, specifically using Python (Flask) for the backend. I've found a few solutions such as `flask-login` and `flask-security`.

To my understanding, `flask-login` doesn't actually do any authentication leaving all the JWT type work to me, whereas `flask-security` handles these scenarios.

With that being said, I have a few questions:

1. Seems to me that `flask-security` is built on top of `flask-login`. So it seems better (at least to me) to use that library instead of trying to reinvent the wheel in terms of redesigning authentication. The last update to `flask-security` was on April 23, 2020. This leads me to believe that people are still active in trying to find ways to improve it. That said, is `flask-security` the better option of the two?
2. I also want to use this in production. So would this is also a viable solution?

Answer (score 18):

Flask-Security is now deprecated, so I wouldn't recommend using it in production. There is a fork of it called [Flask Security Too](https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but it doesn't seem very widely followed.

To be honest even when it was maintained it wasn't my favourite as I think it tried to do too much.

Flask-Login on the other hand is a solid library. It is very "flasky" in the sense that it is low level and deals with the really annoying stuff (creating a session, persisting it with cookies, delivering a current_user, putting certain routes behind a login_required decorator) and then letting you design your own flow and pull in the libraries you want.

For instance if you want social login or OAuth token storage then [Flask-Dance](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which integrates nicely with Flask-Login and is actively maintained, smashes Flask-Social which integrates with Flask-Security.

There is also Flask-User, which gets good reviews but last commit was in 2019, which is a little scary.

Answer (score 2):

`Flask-Security-Too`, while it can be complex if you try to use all of its features, proves to actually be pretty easy to set up production-ready applications. It is actively maintained. I have a few working projects in production using this library (`v4.x.x`). Not too long ago, there has been a `v5.x.x` release as well.
You should definitely check that out.

- Flask-Security-Too: https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/
- My Example Application: https://github.com/hrishikeshrt/flask-bootstrap-anywhere

Answer (score 0):

the two answers this has r contradicting themselves, so let me add my vote :

from what im aware, flask-login is secure enough for production environments, and i think u could easily also do this to improve the security of it :

```py
    app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE"] = "strict"
    app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE"] = True
    app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY"] = True

    app.config["REMEMBER_COOKIE_SAMESITE"] = "strict"
    app.config["REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE"] = True
```

at least what i do /shrug